# Jquery working everywhere apart from Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm new to js/jquery. I have this script and it's working everywhere apart from firefox. I've tried the .preventDefault bt maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.logo')
      .mouseover(function (){
        var hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16);
          $('.inside').css('fill', hue);})
      .mouseout(function () {
        $('.inside').css('fill', '#F4FF29')
      });

      $('.logo')
      .mouseover(function (){
        var hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16);
          $(".centre").css('fill', hue);})
      .mouseout(function () {
        $('.centre').css('fill', '#343434') 
      });

      $('.logo')
      .mouseover(function (){
        var hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16);
          $('.outside').css('fill', hue);})
      .mouseout(function () {
        $('.outside').css('fill', '#FFFFFF') 
      });
    }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: In what way exactly does it not work? Does *anything* happen? Do you get errors in the console?

Comment: And there are no calls to `.preventDefault()` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Firstly those 3 events can be converted into just one. Secondly, .preventDefaul is not needed lastly what is not working with it?

Comment: Thanks for prompt replies. As I said, I'm pretty new to it and I don't quite know how to convert it into one function. Basically there's nothing going on, no errors in the console.

Comment: Also, I can't see the colours changing in css at all in the inspector

Comment: I've added it as an answer for you

Comment: Well then there you go, fill is not used to change colors, you need to use `background-color`; I'll edit the answer and you can try that. Unless fill is the right attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the following worked for me in firefox:

add

```
$('.inside').css('fill', '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
$(".centre").css('fill', '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
$('.outside').css('fill', '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
```

in the mouseover

Comment: HA! Works! You're a real wizard :)))

Comment: No problem. Please if the answer was helpful click on the vote-up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I' just giving a little tip not the answer since your new to the js.

Firstly we will shrink your code:

```
$('.logo')
    .mouseover(function (){
        $('.inside').css('fill', Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
        $(".centre").css('fill', Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
        $('.outside').css('fill', Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
        $('.inside').css('fill', '#F4FF29');
        $('.centre').css('fill', '#343434');
        $('.outside').css('fill', '#FFFFFF');
    });
```

We will remove the `var hue` because its only being used once in each call but in your case the reason we won't use it is because you want to use new generated numbers for each element not the same one.n So use a variable if you will use it in multiple areas.

We will also add each operation in it's respected event

And to test where it stops working, do an alert in each event to see where it stops working or a console.log after each `.css` call

Comment: Thanks very much. Looks much better. So I've tried to change the 'fill' to 'background-color' but it then stops working at all. In Chrome & Safari it does work but only with fill. Firefox console returns the alert, but doesn't change the colour. Ideas how to fix?

Comment: Can you paste the entire code you have so I can test it? Or what element is `.inside`?

Comment: Sure, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wout/Vac2Q/)
It doesn't really work there either (strange)

Comment: I take it, you want it to stay in the container right?

Comment: Oops I'm sorry, it's not the right fiddle link, let me paste the code below once again

Comment: Would you also like to fix the first fiddle it make it stay within the canvas as well?

Comment: There: http://jsfiddle.net/foch/zs5xtzqu/
Also, thanks for the tip with variables, I do indeed use it in more places and other pages, I'm going to have a separate js file with global variables. Can I set a global function as well and then just call it when needed?

Comment: Yes you can,infact that  is something I use a lot. Simply create the `global_function.js` file and in every page where you declare your `jquery` include the `global_function.js` as follows:

    `<script src="assets/js/autosize.min.js"></script>`

 and all the variables and functions in it is accessible.  But be warned that if you add functions that needs another plugin included for example autosize, then `<script src="assets/js/autosize.min.js"></script>` must be included in all files you have the `global_function.js` added.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="col-1">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="info.html">Information</a></li>
  </ul>
  <svg class="logo" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="610.8 105 699.7 692.3" enable-background="new 610.8 105 699.7 692.3" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="inside" d="M910.3,451.1l50.4-87.3l50.4,87.3l-50.4,87.3L910.3,451.1z"/>
    <path class="centre" d="M959.8,538.1l50.4-87.3H1111l-50.4,87.3H959.8z"/>
    <path class="centre" d="M810.2,451.7l50.4-87.3h100.8L911,451.7H810.2z"/>
    <path class="outside" d="M1010.4,451.7l-49.8-86.4h-99.8L810.4,278h200.6l100.4,173.7H1010.4z"/>
    <path class="outside" d="M910.6,624.4L810.4,450.7h100.8l49.8,86.4h99.8l50.4,87.3L910.6,624.4z"/>
    <path class="inside" d="M1059.9,537.5l49.8-86.4l-99.7-172.7l50.4-87.3l150.2,260.1l-100.4,173.7L1059.9,537.5z"/>
    <path class="inside"d="M710.8,451.1l100.4-173.7l50.4,87.3l-50,86.4l99.8,172.7L861,711.2L710.8,451.1z"/>
    <path class="centre" d="M760.9,191.5h300.4l-50.4,87.3H811.5l-99.8,172.7H610.9L760.9,191.5z"/>
    <path class="centre" d="M860,710.8l50.4-87.3h199.5l99.8-172.7h100.8l-150.2,260.1L860,710.8z"/>
    <path class="outside" d="M1209.8,451.6l-149.6-259.2H760.9L710.5,105h400.2l200,346.4L1209.8,451.6z"/>
    <path class="outside" d="M810.8,797.2l-200-346.4h100.8L861.2,710h299.3l50.4,87.3L810.8,797.2z"/>
  </svg>

<!-- colorful logo hover -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.logo')
  .mouseover(function (){
      $('.inside').css('fill', Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
      console.log("inside");
      $(".centre").css('fill', Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
      console.log("centre");
      $('.outside').css('fill', Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16));
      console.log("outside");
  })
  .mouseout(function () {
      $('.inside').css('fill', '#F4FF29');
      $('.centre').css('fill', '#343434');
      $('.outside').css('fill', '#FFFFFF');
  });
</script>
</div>
```